# Ubuntu 14.04 - After update root disk /dev/sda is labelled /dev/root

Tags: mount, fstab, disk, df

After updating with `apt-get upgrade` the root partition `/dev/sda` is now labelled `/dev/root`.

This is a KVM vm which is why it's showing as `/dev/sda` rather than `/dev/sda1`

I did not update the kernel.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

This creates an inconsistency on the system which is breaking automation and monitoring scripts. Rather than rework all of those, I'd rather just remove/disable the labeling.

It does not look to be kernel related as I have 2 servers on the same kernel, one that shows this behaviour (which I updated) and one that does not.

I don't have any device labels set, and don't have any udev rules either. Researched online but have not found anything about what is causing this.

Does anyone know which package is causing this?

Here's some examples of the inconsistency this is creating:

```
root@ server1:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        47G  2.9G   44G   7% /

root@ server1:~# cat /proc/mounts
/dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0


root@ server1:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc        /proc        proc    defaults                       0 0
/dev/sda   /            ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro      0 1
/dev/sdb   none         swap    sw                             0 0


root@ server1:~# cat /proc/diskstats
   1       0 ram0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
   8      16 sdb 290 161 3856 53 51 308 2872 33 0 73 86
   8       0 sda 32978 1444 1088660 30486 3436572 2964281 69967928 1296110 0 369590 1329923
   9       0 md0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks